# use NVL in LEFT JOIN oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables:

```
Table A:      TableB:
ID            ID    Value
1             2     0.5
2             3     10
3
```

my query:

```
SELECT A.ID,B.VALUE FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID;
```

result:

```
ID    Value
1      
2     0.5
3     10
```

I want to replace the null value with '-' and I tried using NVL (B.VALUE, '-'), but that doesn't work so what should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Doesn't work" isn't a very helpful description of your problem. My guess is you got "ORA-01722: invalid number", because `NVL( B.value, '-' )` will try to cast the second argument to the same datatype as the first and you can't cast "-" to a number. But if you wrap the first argument in `TO_CHAR`, it works, as in:

```
SELECT A.ID, NVL( TO_CHAR( B.VALUE ), '-' ) FROM TableA A LEFT JOIN TableB B ON A.ID = B.ID;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9b63a/4) example